# "so" or "therefore"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions, phrase-meaning

I usually double check my English using Google Translate. I paste my phrase in English (translated by myself) and I see how it translates it back to Italian. If the meaning is the one I had in mind then I'm quite sure I translated Italian to English correctly (almost, at least).

But I'm quite surprised today because I wrote this sentence in Google Translate

> I'll be on vacation from August, 1st to August, 25th **so** the
>   support will be discontinued for a while

and it translated to Italian in a way that the meaning is this:

> As the support will be discontinued for a while, I'll be on vacation
>   from etc...

I changed the English sentence to:

> I'll be on vacation from August, 1st to August, 25th **therefore** the
>   support will be discontinued for a while

and I got the correct meaning, which is that I can't ensure the availability of support because I'll be on vacation.

Is Google Translate right? I always use *so* and never use *therefore* so I'm worried I said a lot of nonsense all these years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Google Translate right?

No, it is not.  Google Translate is an awful, awful thing in situations like these.

> [the rest of your question]

*So* is perfectly fine the way you used it (I'd personally get rid of *the* because it's fine to say *I'll be on vacation … so support will be discontinued for a while*).

The reason (maybe) GT was freaking out about it is that the conjunction *so* can be used in a few other ways and can mean other things.  For example, it can be used as such, to indicate a goal or an aim.  In this case, it means "in order to" or "in order that"

> I went to the store **so** I could purchase some asparagus.

This way, *therefore* would not work at all.  Translate gets very confused about things like this, since it's not entirely sure how you're using such versatile little words.

And, on top of that, *so* can also be an adverb (kind of).  It can mean *to such an extent* or *to the same extent* or simply as a reference to something that is true:

> I was driving so fast I went back in time.
>
> I thought so.

Etcetera.  And on top of *that* there's a whole bunch of tiny expressions and idioms that use *so* in a way that isn't covered by this answer, or the New Oxford American Dictionary, from which I drew inspiration.

That said (back to your question), *therefore* works too, and is more specific to your sentence.  But to me, it sounds a bit more weird, like you're speaking too robotically.  Other ways you could've done that:

> I'll be on vacation …, thus support will be discontinued
>
> I'll be on vacation …, and support will be discontinued
>
> I'll be on vacation …, and as a result, support will be discontinued

All of these are fine, and since some of the words used may also have other possible meanings, Google Translate will be garbage on all of this.

Answer (score 1):

*So* and *therefore* are interchangeable here.  However, your use of *so* is harder to understand than Google's use of *therefore* because of the lack of a comma.  In either case, whether you use *so* or *therefore*, you really need a comma, but this fact sticks out more with the word *so* here. (Also the commas you have between August and 25th or 1st are not necessary.)

> I'll be on vacation from August 1st to August 25th, so the support will be discontinued for a while.
>
> I'll be on vacation from August 1st to August 25th, therefore the support will be discontinued for a while.

Actually with therefore, it probably technically should be a semi-colon:

> I'll be on vacation from August 1st to August 25th; therefore the support will be discontinued for a while.